# Multiple condition in 'if' loop to compare values of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have 2 columns in index 12 and 13 of dataframe df_2. I want to compare 'i+1' row of 2 columns with 'i' row of the same column. **Only** if both row doesn't match then i want to increment the value i assign. But the code i have written is failing somewhere. What is the problem?

```
h_count = 0
current = "G"
status = []
for i in range(len(df_2)):
    if (i < len(df_2)-1) and ((df_2.iloc[i+1, 12] and df_2.iloc[i+1, 13]) == (df_2.iloc[i, 12] and df_2.iloc[i, 13])):
        status.append(f"G{h_count}")
    else:
        status.append(f"G{h_count}")
        h_count += 1
```

[image]

I want it to be G4 here because one of the value doesn't match above. I think it is comparing only second column.

PN: I know I can modify loop by comparing one column first and then compare second column inside that loop. but how can I do it in one condition?

Comment: the problem is not with the `if`statement, but with when you count `h_count` up

Comment: Yea i realized that. how to tackle this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is in decalring the conditions. What you should do is like the following example

```
if x == y and z == y and b == y:
    do smth
```

what you did is

```
if x and z and b == y:
    do smthg
    # here python will try to find any correct condition, not to restrict the result to all declared conditions
```

Comment: the problem is with h-count .. im thinking about how to resolve it

Comment: normally it shoul be done like: if elem is not in list: list.append(elem) count += 1 else count = 1 , lots of tutorials about count elem. search for it.